# Detach keyup for Space bar and Enter keys

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery 3.+, how can I detach *keyup* on buttons triggered by the *Space bar* and *Enter* keys?

I have something like this:

```
$("#MAIN").on("keyup", "#scrub-btn.buttonOn:focus", function(e){

var allthesekeys = ( e.which == 107 || e.which == 109 || e.which == 96 || e.which == 97 || e.which == 98 || e.which == 99 || e.which == 100 || e.which == 101 || e.which == 102 || e.which == 103 || e.which == 104 || e.which == 105 );

        if ( allthesekeys ){

        // Do the scrubbing here...

        } else {

        $(this).off("keyup");

// Can we use $(this) here? Why are Space bar and Enter keys ignoring this?

        }
});
```

Must I rethink my strategy? Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: You want the event listener to be removed if the user types any of those keys, or you just want those keys to be ignored?

Comment: I want the event listener to be removed whenever the Space bar, the Enter key, and any other keys not listed in the var are pressed. The "else" condition exposes this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using event delegation...

So the event handler (the function) is attached to `#MAIN` to handle the event occuring in `#scrub-btn.buttonOn`.

`$(this)` represents the element where the event occurs... **Not** the element delegated to handle the event. That is why the `.off()` is not working.

Use `$("#MAIN")` instead... Or `$(this).closest("#MAIN")` because that is the element which has to be detached from the event listener.

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/brBdBb?editors=1111)

I am tempted to suggest a more consise way to write your condition:

```
  var allthesekeys = [107,109,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105];

  if ( allthesekeys.indexOf(e.which) > -1 ){...}
```

It will be easier to maintain...
;)

Comment: Awesome! I also tested in Codepen for button and works flawless. Yes, I happen to verbose code a lot for explanatory reasons, but will finally concise my code as suggested, Thx!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: I cannot use e.preventDefault() nor return false since those keys trigger other functions upon keypress and click.

Comment: why not? If they are in another event listener this does not affect the other listeners. If they are in the same one, after you preventDefault you can always call `.trigger('keyup')` if you must

Comment: With e.preventDefault()  or Return false, the Enter key works but still ignores the detached keyup, while the Space bar keyup jams all processes. Let me try to fiddle my way for you. Thx for input.